# how to make ng-model work with double/float values?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this for the double/float value.

```
<input type="text"   ng-model='floatvalue'/>
```

it isn't retrieving the value but saves perfectly :////

Any solutions???

Comment: Can you show you JS , and what is the error, Can you explain more

Comment: works for me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s3po1mo5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type="number"` to automatically parse to a `Number` type:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="floatvalue"/>
```

The `number` type supports things like `min`, `max` and `step` attributes.